# jquery validator - custom design

Tags: jquery

I have set of input fields. If any of them incorrect, I'm displaying it in bubble message above the control. What i did is:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element)
        var message = error.html();
        error.html('<div class="innerError"><div class="message">' + message + '</div><div class="corner"></div></div>');
    }
```

Now, when field is invalid, message displayed as expected, but when I focus out of the field, without changing it or even if i do change it, the inner div (message) remains...

thanks in advanced!

Comment: the question is: why the custom added html is not behaving like it should be...

Answer (score 0):

a simple example, validating a textbox

```
<form action="/">
    <input type="text" /><span class="error"></span><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

$(function () {

    $('input:submit').click(function (e) {

        $('input:text').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().find('span').html("input text is blank");
            }
        });

    });

    $('input:text').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $(this).parent().find('span').text("");
        }
    });

});
```

so basically you would need to apply .blur event (focus out) and re-validate the input
if is valid then remove the error message else leave it.